# Sharing constants between Android , iOS and Dart in a Flutter Project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-platform-channel

Is there any workaround to share constant variables between the android ,iOS and dart code? This can be especially useful when using Platform Channels as the Channel name, method names and argument key names are kept in a constants file and alternately the same file is created in kotlin and swift to match . Can we avoid this duplication by keeping a common file that can be shared and accessed by the 3 platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding unified Platform Channels usage [pigeon](https://pub.dev/packages/pigeon) package could be used to simplify the whole process. But for now, it does not resolve in particular constants sharing.

Answer (score -1):

- you can use flutter run —dart-define MY_DATA=SomeString. [see](https://dartcode.org/docs/using-dart-define-in-flutter/)
- example

```
static class AppConfig{
  static const String MY_DATA= String.fromEnvironment("MY_DATA",
      defaultValue: 'initValue');
}

void test(){
     print(AppConfig.MY_DATA);
}
```

Comment: How does this help with sharing constants with native code?

Comment: Can intercept the parameters passed in by --dart-define at compile time and act on Android build.gradle and iOS Runner Sell Script